# Program 'npx.cmd' failed to run

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, npm, npx

I'm trying to create a JS app using the VSCode Terminal. To do so, I'm typing in the following: `npx @knowledgehut/create-js-app my-blog` but I get the following error as a result:

```
ResourceUnavailable: Program 'npx.cmd' failed to run: An error occurred trying to start process 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\npx.cmd' with working directory 'C:\Users\belen'. The system cannot find the file specified.At line:1 char:1
npx @knowledgehut/create-js-app my-blog`
```

I have already unistalled an reinstalled VSCode and same with Node.js. I have of course restarted my computer because sometimes that does the trick but nothing worked.

VS Code version: Code 1.69.2 (3b889b0, 2022-07-18T16:12:52.460Z)
OS version: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22000
Restricted Mode: No

Comment: Try installing the latest npx using `npm install -g npx@latest` or running it using `npx@latest`?

Comment: I tried that as well but I keep on getting a similar error:

ResourceUnavailable: Program 'npm.cmd' failed to run: An error occurred trying to start process 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd' with working directory 'C:\Users\belen'. The system cannot find the file specified.At line:1 char:1
+ npm install -g npx@latest
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.